# how to sum up 3 integers values to get the final count

Tags: python-3.x

## I wrote a code where I want to get the final sum value of 3 integers which is in iteration way. I am able to get the values added but I want the final value to be printed only.

```
import boto3
import datetime

snapdate = input("please Enter the date you want to restore the data from in YYYY-DD-MM format :")
```

## date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(snapdate, '%Y-%m-%d')

## print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())

```
print(snapdate)
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
#instance = boto3.rp-esource('ec2')
#snapshots = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values': ['aws-test-1']}])['Snapshots']
def get_snapshots():
    response = ec2.describe_snapshots(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['aws-test-1']}]
)
return response["Snapshots"]
```

## snapshots = [s for s in get_snapshots() if s["StartTime"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H') == snapdate]

```
snapshots = [s for s in get_snapshots() if s["StartTime"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == snapdate]
```

## print(snapshots)

```
sum = 0
for snap in snapshots:
    snap_ids = snap['SnapshotId']
    snap_date = snap['StartTime']
    snaplst = [snap_ids]
    snapleng = (len(snaplst))
    sum = sum + snapleng
    print(sum)
```

I am getting the result as :

1
2
3

But I want the final value "3" to be printed, any suggestion would be a great help

Thanks
Suddhasil

Comment: We can debug it much easily and tell you where you are going wrong if you paste the actual code here.

Comment: Also your `for` loop looks unformatted, not sure if you are doing the same, hence please post the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a print statement inside the loop. Print the final value outside the loop to get just '3' as output.

```
sum = 0
for snap in snapshots:
      snap_ids = snap['SnapshotId']
      snap_date = snap['StartTime']
      snaplst = [snap_ids]
      snapleng = (len(snaplst))
      sum = sum + snapleng
print(sum)
```

Comment: Hi Gary, ohh this simple not came in my thought :-( Many thanks Gary!